# Why the InsertResult is empty in typeorm and nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

When I tried to insert some data to the repository.

```
const newChild = await queryRunner.manager.insert<Child>('child', child);
_height.childId = newChild.generatedMaps[0].id;
```

I suffered following error.

`error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

I checked `InsertResult`

`console.log(newChild);`

```
InsertResult {
  identifiers: [],
  generatedMaps: [],
  raw: OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 7,
    serverStatus: 3,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0
  }
}
```

It seems that `identifiers` are empty.

What could be the cause of this?

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me needed to set the "entites" property in the typeorm config.

Something like this solved my problem:

ormconfig.json

```
{
...
"username": "root",
"password": "admin",
"database": "test",
...

"entities": [
  "dist/**/entity/**/*.js"
],
```